# SQL - need help creating query

Tags: sql

Table: `customer`

```
Customer number          PRODUCT_ID            
----------------         -----             
12345                    1            
23456                    2            
12345                    3
23456                    3
12345                    4
```

I need to create a query that will list all customers having 2 or more PRODUCT_ID > 2

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.customer_number, count(c.product_id) as product_count
from customer c
group by c.customer_number
having count(c.product_id) > 2
```

You should read through this explanation of how `HAVING` clause should be used in conjunction with aggregate functions: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Thank you for answer and reference